# How to handle redirect sent by Play framework controller in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, playframework

In my controller, I have a method that I am calling using jquery AJAX. The controller method sends a redict(some.view.in.my.app) on success. How can I load this page in the client browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NOT send a redirect as a response to AJAX request, instead you can send `ok(jsonObj)` status containing for an example JSON object or even simple string with URL to new target page (or `badRequest()` in case of fail).

Next you can perform ordinary JavaScript redirect using common `window.location.href` in case of `GET` redirect, or fill and submit some hidden form if `POST` redirect is required.